# Add new OpenCV-Module into an existing project in Visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opencv, ocr

How can I add, without using cmake, a missing module (like opencv/text) to an existing OpenCV project in Visual Studio 2017 ?

Can I download the missing module from here https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules and copy it into the modules folder of opencv ?

Comment: No, rebuild opencv with the contrib module you need and update includes and linked libs